# Select min (also max & avg) from table together with timestamp of the event

Tags: mysql, mariadb, grafana

I've got several tables like this:

```
> "dsid"    "tag"   "timestamp" "value"  
> "989" "EE"    "1445162347"    "931.647"
> "990" "PO"    "1445162347"    "0.087" 
> "991" "EE"    "1445163247"    "931.669"
> "992" "PO"    "1445163247"    "0.089"
> "993" "EE"    "1445164147"    "931.692"
> "994" "PO"    "1445164147"    "0.085"
> "995" "EE"    "1445165047"    "931.715"
> "996" "PO"    "1445165047"    "0.090"
```

EE is the count (in kWh) of an electricity meter and PO the Power (in kW) on the meter, data is read from the meter every 15Mins and written to the database.

I'm looking for the MAX of all value's with TAG "PO", that's the reason why I'm excluding all "EE" TAG's. I'm want code that returns the highest value and it's according timestamp which has TAG "PO"

I intent to use that code to extent a grafana dashboard (which already exist's) with the MAX, MIN & AVG value and their according timestamp.

This is the Code I have so far but it seems to always select the first value in the time-range I feed it in the WHERE clause:

```
'''SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as time_sec,
    '1P2' AS Meter,
    tag as metric,
    MIN(value) AS MIN,
    MAX(VALUE) AS MAX,
    AVG(VALUE) AS AVG
  FROM `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2`
  WHERE TAG NOT IN ('EE')
'''
```

Currently I get this output:

```
"time_sec"  "Meter" "metric"    "MIN"   "MAX" "AVG"
"2015-10-13 08:14:07"   "1P2"   "PO"    "0.000000"  "6.404" "3.2"
```

What I'ld is something like that:

```
"time_sec"  "Meter" "metric"    "MIN"   "MAX"  "AVG"
"2015-10-13 08:14:07"   "1P2"   "PO"    "0.1"   ""  ""
"2015-12-13 10:14:07"   "1P2"   "PO"    ""  "6.404"  ""
""  "1P2"   "PO"    ""  ""  "3.2"
```

As requested here's some line's of insert script code:

```
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (909, 'EE', 1445126346, '930.647', 1445125500, 1445126400, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (910, 'PO', 1445126346, '0.088', 1445125500, 1445126400, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (911, 'EE', 1445127246, '930.669', 1445126400, 1445127300, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (912, 'PO', 1445127246, '0.087', 1445126400, 1445127300, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (913, 'EE', 1445128146, '930.691', 1445127300, 1445128200, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (914, 'PO', 1445128146, '0.087', 1445127300, 1445128200, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (915, 'EE', 1445129046, '930.718', 1445128200, 1445129100, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (916, 'PO', 1445129046, '0.138', 1445128200, 1445129100, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (917, 'EE', 1445129947, '930.752', 1445129100, 1445130000, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (918, 'PO', 1445129947, '0.134', 1445129100, 1445130000, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (919, 'EE', 1445130847, '930.782', 1445130000, 1445130900, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (920, 'PO', 1445130847, '0.088', 1445130000, 1445130900, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (921, 'EE', 1445131747, '930.804', 1445130900, 1445131800, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (922, 'PO', 1445131747, '0.087', 1445130900, 1445131800, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (923, 'EE', 1445132647, '930.826', 1445131800, 1445132700, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (924, 'PO', 1445132647, '0.086', 1445131800, 1445132700, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (925, 'EE', 1445133547, '930.848', 1445132700, 1445133600, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (926, 'PO', 1445133547, '0.086', 1445132700, 1445133600, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (927, 'EE', 1445134447, '930.870', 1445133600, 1445134500, 0);
INSERT INTO `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2` (`dsid`, `tag`, `timestamp`, `value`, `startts`, `correctts`, `isfixed`) VALUES (928, 'PO', 1445134447, '0.087', 1445133600, 1445134500, 0);
```

The additional columns after value are of no relevance...

THX to @symcbean I'm now a good bit closer to what I need to achieve:

```
SELECT records.*, aggregated.*
 FROM
 (
 SELECT
 from_unixtime(TIMESTAMP),
 tag AS metric,
 MAX(VALUE) AS 1P2_MAX,
 AVG(VALUE) AS 1P2_AVG
 FROM `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2`
 WHERE TAG NOT IN ('EE')
 AND from_unixtime(TIMESTAMP BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1546297200) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1577833199))
 ) records JOIN
 (
 SELECT
 tag AS metric,
 MAX(VALUE) AS 1P2_MAX,
 AVG(VALUE) AS 1P2_AVG
 FROM `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2`
 WHERE TAG NOT IN ('EE')
 AND from_unixtime(TIMESTAMP BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1546297200) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1577833199))
 GROUP BY metric
 ) aggregated ON
 records.metric=aggregated.metric
```

I've already used three of those in grafana got a nice table, but it always picks the first time value in the database as timestamp. But I need it output the timestamp from 1P2_MAX. This way I'll know when exactly the MAX occured...

Currently the output is like this:

```
"from_unixtime(TIMESTAMP)"  "metric"    "1P2_MAX"   "1P2_AVG"   "metric"    "1P2_MAX"   "1P2_AVG"
"2015-10-13 08:14:07"   "PO"    "6.404" "0,4250229947656381"    "PO"    "6.404" "0,4250229947656381"
```

Comment: can you add insert script ? - sample to try on for fixes ?

Comment: My SQL coding experience is very basic so generally no :-(

Comment: you can simply right click `Export recordset to an external file` on your `select *` result - and save the file with `.sql` - which is basically your table inserts

Comment: Didn't get your question, sure I can export the data and put it in here...

Comment: Can there be different tags with the same timestamp? Which tag should be returned?

Comment: @Barmar yes there's always one timestamp with (in that case) two tags. I'm using:
    WHERE TAG NOT IN ('EE')
to exclude the unwanted TAG

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), tag`.

(Depending on how your DBMS is configured you may need to include the literal in the grouped attributes).

This is a rather trivial SQL problem - so much so that its quicker to type the answer here rather than search for a duplicate.

However although that answers the question you asked - it looks like you are asking the wrong question. Although your example data has multiple rows with the same tag and timestamp, this seems a bit strange. I suspect you might want to round the time values to get larger bins if you are really interested in aggregate values.

**UPDATE based on comments below**

If you want the aggregate values without matching these to a specific time....

```
SELECT records.*, aggregated.*
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2`
  WHERE TAG NOT IN ('EE')
  AND timestamp BETWEEN _____ AND _____
) records JOIN
(
  SELECT
  tag AS metric,
  MIN(value) AS minval,
  MAX(VALUE) AS maxval,
  AVG(VALUE) AS avgval
  FROM `WSE_KA-KHW_1P2`
  WHERE TAG NOT IN ('EE')
  AND timestamp BETWEEN _____ AND _____
  GROUP BY tag
) aggregated ON
records.tag=aggregated.tag
```

But that's something different from what you asked in the subsequent edits to your question:

> I'm want code that returns the highest value and it's according timestamp which has TAG "PO"

That's a new requirement. And while in your sample data, PO is "NOT IN (EE)" it does not necessaril follow that this expression is communtative. Leaving that aside, you seem to be asking for the "groupwise maximum" - which you can solve by using the [max concat trick](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) or a [sub-query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: I've tried several different other questions but couldn't get code from those that gave me the expected output. I'll try to make your suggestion work and return...

Comment: If add the suggested
    GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), tag
I get an output of every single line from the table, what I want is only one line with the max value. For AVG and MIN and can use the same query later in an additional panel on grafana

Comment: No - adding GROUP BY will aggregate values with the same timestamp and tag - this is not unique in the dataset you posted, but see the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @Smycbean I'm looking for the MAX of all value's with TAG "PO", that's the reason why I'm excluding all "EE" TAG's. I'm want code that returns the highest value and it's according timestamp which has TAG "PO". I don't know how to ask my question more specific... :-(

Comment: THX to your addition I got closer, but still have the wrong timestamp in the output. Seems to be first value in the DB but not the time when MAX occured